# QBASIC program is returning an 'inf' output

Tags: floating-point, qbasic

I'm starting to learn QBASIC for  while, but the first test is something I can't understand fully...
**There is a part about the** ***y*** **variable which is returning** *"inf"* **and I can't understand WHY**...I searched up that in Google but its just showing *"inf"* error. If it IS an error at all, it should not run at all but the program is running beautifully. Here's the code :

```
Print "Hello World"
x = 123
Print x;
y = 123^210 * x
Print y
```

And here's the output :

```
Hello World
123 inf
```

> Is it because The power's too much ?? It should show an error then, but the code's running perfectly...

Comment: `123^210` is a pretty large number with 439 digits - I would assume that QBasic cannot handle such large numbers

Comment: I just tried it under QBasic and does actually trigger an "Overflow" error…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The QBasic 1.1 Help file gives the following limits:

> ```
>                            Maximum                  Minimum
>                             ----------------------   -----------------------
> Variable-name length        40 characters             1 character
> String length               32,767 characters         0 characters
> Integers                    32,767                   -32,768
> Long integers               2,147,483,647            -2,147,483,648
> Single-precision numbers:
>   Positive                  3.402823E+38              2.802597E-45
>   Negative                 -2.802597E-45             -3.402823E+38
> Double-precision numbers:
>   Positive                  1.79769313486231D+308     4.940656458412465D-324
>   Negative                 -4.940656458412465D-324   -1.79769313486231D+308
> ```
>
> **<sub>From: [QBASIC 1.1 Help file](https://hwiegman.home.xs4all.nl/qb-man/index.html) Subsection: Name String and Number Limits</sub>**

And in the Character set, we find that the <caret>-character represents the exponentiation as a mathematical operator.
Hence, the value `123^210` is, by far, larger than the maximum double-precision positive number which is `2^1023 × (1 + (1 − 2^−52))`

```
2^1023 × (1 + (1 − 2^−52)) < (2^6)^210 = 2^1260 < 123^210 = (2^7-2^4-1)^210
```